# OpenGL-ES: is it possible to use an integer surface as a color attachment?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, glsles

I am writing a game for **Android** devices which uses the **Android NDK** and **OpenGL-ES**.  I am rendering an image to a **framebuffer** and then using that information in the CPU.  More precision would be better, so I used:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

to create the surface for the (only) color attachment.  I selected it because it was the only 32 bit per color surface type that was usable as a color attachment listed on the OpenGL-ES page for glTexImage2D.

This works fine on some devices, but on an Android 6 HTC phone, I get the following errors output from the phone:

```
E/Adreno-ES20: <core_glClear:62>: WARNING: glClear called on an integer buffer. Buffer contents will be undefined
    <oxili_check_sp_rb_fmt_mismatch:86>: WARNING : Rendertarget does not match shader output type.
E/Adreno-ES20: <core_glClear:62>: WARNING: glClear called on an integer buffer. Buffer contents will be undefined
E/Adreno-ES20: <oxili_check_sp_rb_fmt_mismatch:86>: WARNING : Rendertarget does not match shader output type.
```

Note: These messages are in a log file, no OpenGL errors were returned with glGetError.

Am I getting this error just because it is a buggy ancient phone, or is there a problem with what I am doing?

The OpenGL-ES page on glTexImage2D states that the surface can be used as a color attachment:

[Khronos glTexImage2D reference page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

The output from the fragment shader is a mediump vec4 (gl_FragColor), but that cannot be changed, right?

Note: the result I get from the code is just the clear color on the phone with the error in the log file (and one other phone which is a later model of the same brand).  There are no errors returned from glGetError.  And glCheckFramebufferStatus returned that the framebuffer was complete.

Code for creating the framebuffer:

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_depthMap);
checkGraphicsError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthMap);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, width, height, 0,
             GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
checkGraphicsError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
checkGraphicsError();

glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_depthMapFBO);
checkGraphicsError();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_depthMapFBO);
checkGraphicsError();

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthMap, 0);
checkGraphicsError();


glGenTextures(1, &m_colorImage);
checkGraphicsError();
glActiveTexture(activeTextureIndicator);
checkGraphicsError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_colorImage);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER,
             GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
checkGraphicsError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
checkGraphicsError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
checkGraphicsError();

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, attachmentIndicator, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_colorImage, 0);
checkGraphicsError();

GLenum rc = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (rc != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    std::string c;
    switch (rc) {
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
            c = "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT";
            break;
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
            c = "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT";
            break;
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS:
            c = "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS";
            break;
        case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
            c = "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED";
            break;
        default:
            c = "Unknown return code.";
    }
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Framebuffer is not complete, returned: ") + c);
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
checkGraphicsError();
```

**Update**: It turns out if you use OpenGL ES GLSL version 1.00, you cannot change the output types.  I was using GLSL 1.00 to be able to support lower end phones and old phones.  I changed the code so that it would use GLSL 3.00 if the call to eglCreateContext with EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION set to 3 succeeded, otherwise it uses GLSL version 1.00 and does not use the integer surface.  I am reading the result of the render with glReadPixels:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data.data());
```

I changed from calling glClear to calling glClearBufferuiv/glClearBufferfv, if OpenGL ES 3.0 is being used:

```
if (m_surfaceDetails->useIntTexture) {
    std::array<GLuint, 4> color = {0, 0, 0, 4294967295};
    glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR, 0, color.data());
    checkGraphicsError();
    GLfloat depthBufferClearValue = 1.0f;
    glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &depthBufferClearValue);
    checkGraphicsError();
} else {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    checkGraphicsError();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkGraphicsError();
}
```

This works well for all my test devices except for that old HTC phone with android 6.0.  On that phone, I am getting no GL errors programmatically or printed out to the debug log (i.e. the previously stated errors about calling glClear on an integer surface are gone).  However, I get rgb = 1073741824, a=4294967295.  The result I was looking for my test was rgb=2147483647 and a=4294967295. I didn't get the clear color of rgb=0 and a=4294967295, I got a different (weird) value for rgb.  Any other ideas, or is the phone just buggy?

Listed below are my new vertex and fragment shaders using OpenGL ES GLSL 3.00.

My vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform float nearestDepth;
uniform float farthestDepth;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;

out vec3 fragColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
    vec4 pos = model * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    float z = (pos.z/pos.w - farthestDepth)/(nearestDepth - farthestDepth);
    if (z > 1.0) {
        z = 1.0;
    } else if (z < 0.0) {
        z = 0.0;
    }
    fragColor = vec3(z, z, z);
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 0) out uvec4 fragColorOut;

void main() {
    float maxUint = 4294967295.0;
    fragColorOut = uvec4(
        uint(fragColor.r * maxUint),
        uint(fragColor.g * maxUint),
        uint(fragColor.b * maxUint),
        uint(maxUint));
}
```

**Update 2**

Thanks for all the comments.  I ran some tests and changed my shaders in response to the comments:

So I checked the precision of highp and mediump floats and ints with glGetShaderPrecisionFormat and here's what I got:

```
GLint range[2];
GLint precision;
glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_HIGH_FLOAT, range, &precision);
// range[0] = 127
// range[1] = 127
// precision = 23

glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_HIGH_INT, range, &precision);
// range[0] = 31
// range[1] = 31
// precision = 0

glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_MEDIUM_FLOAT, range, &precision);
// range[0] = 15
// range[1] = 15
// precision = 10

glGetShaderPrecisionFormat(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_MEDIUM_INT, range, &precision);
// range[0] = 15
// range[1] = 15
// precision = 0
```

A couple of things to note:

1. highp floats and ints are supported by this phone (or so it says).
2. most of these values match up to the values stated in the OpenGL ES 3 reference card: https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles3-quick-reference-card.pdf - except: the medium precision float which is supposed to have range 14, but claims range 15.

But using mediump in the fragment shader is more correct since all the phones are required to support it.  So I switched to using mediump floats and ints and GL_RGBA16UI surface:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER,
             GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, nullptr);
```

The new shaders are below:

The vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform float nearestDepth;
uniform float farthestDepth;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 inTexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 inNormal;

out mediump vec3 fragColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
    vec4 pos = model * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    float z = (pos.z/pos.w - farthestDepth)/(nearestDepth - farthestDepth);
    if (z > 1.0) {
        z = 1.0;
    } else if (z < 0.0) {
        z = 0.0;
    }
    fragColor = vec3(z, z, z);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;

in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 0) out uvec4 fragColorOut;

void main() {
    // 2^14 the highest value for mediump float. -1 because uint only goes to 2^16-1, see below
    float maxUint = 16383.0;
    fragColorOut = uvec4(
        uint(fragColor.r * maxUint),
        uint(fragColor.g * maxUint),
        uint(fragColor.b * maxUint),
        16383u);

    // mediump uint goes from 0 to 2^16-1
    fragColorOut =  fragColorOut << 2;
}
```

This works for all devices except that android 6 HTC phone.  It returns all 0's for this value.  Again, if I clear the depth surface to 0.8f or so, then I get the clear color.

The reason I am using the integer surface is that GL_RGBA32F and GL_RGBA16F internal formats do not support color rendering in OpenGL ES 3.0.  GL_RGBA8 is supported but is only 8 bits per channel.

**Update 3**

My clear code and read code is below.  I have code to deal with testing this code to see if the integer surface works.  If it does not, useIntTexture will be set to false and the float surface will be used.  So the branch of code that should be examined is if useIntTexture is true.

The only difference in the clear the depth buffer to 0.8f and 1.0f is the value of the variable: depthBufferClearValue.  The below code has it set to 1.0f (as it should be, 0.8f was just an experiment).

```
ref.renderDetails->overrideClearColor(clearColor);
if (m_surfaceDetails->useIntTexture) {
    auto convert = [](float color) -> GLuint {
        return static_cast<GLuint>(std::round(color * std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()));
    };
    std::array<GLuint, 4> color = {convert(clearColor.r), convert(clearColor.g), convert(clearColor.b), convert(clearColor.a)};
    glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR, 0, color.data());
    checkGraphicsError();
    
    // the only difference between the clear 0.8f case and the clear
    // 1.0f case is the below line.  Right now it is clearing 1.0f...
    GLfloat depthBufferClearValue = 1.0f;
    glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &depthBufferClearValue);
    checkGraphicsError();
} else {
    glClearColor(clearColor.r, clearColor.g, clearColor.b, clearColor.a);
    checkGraphicsError();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkGraphicsError();
}

ref.renderDetails->draw(0, ref.commonObjectData, drawObjTable,
        drawObjTable->zValueReferences().begin(), drawObjTable->zValueReferences().end());

glFinish();
checkGraphicsError();

renderDetails::PostprocessingDataInputGL dataVariant;
if (m_surfaceDetails->useIntTexture) {
    /* width * height * 4 color values each a uint16_t in size. */
    std::vector<uint16_t> data(static_cast<size_t>(imageWidth * imageHeight * 4), 0.0f);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    checkGraphicsError();
    glReadPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, colorImageFormat.format, colorImageFormat.type, data.data());
    checkGraphicsError();
    dataVariant = std::move(data);
} else { 
    /* width * height * 4 color values each a char in size. */
    std::vector<uint8_t> data(static_cast<size_t>(imageWidth * imageHeight * 4), 0);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    checkGraphicsError();
    glReadPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, colorImageFormat.format, colorImageFormat.type, data.data());
    checkGraphicsError();
    dataVariant = std::move(data);
}
```

Comment: I suspect the bug is somewhere else, can you show us more of the code around this?

Comment: I added the code for creating the framebuffer.  Let me know if you need to see any other parts of the code.  It is very long :-)  Also, note: glGetError never returned any error messages even though the messages appeared in the log file.  glCheckFramebufferStatus returned that the framebuffer was complete.  The actual problem I see is that all I get as output is the clear color.  There is also a phone that this same code works fine on.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has the above problem, like I did, making two changes solved my problem:

1. I made the relevant "out" variable in the fragment shader into a uvec4, as opposed to just a vec4.
2. I made sure that the "format" argument for my glReadPixels() command was also "_Integer". E.g. in my case, using GL_RED_INTEGER/GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE in the glReadPixels command, instead of GL_RED/GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. While the original question does not explicitly mention glReadPixels(), I imagine it might still be relevant, as getting the data to the CPU was mentioned.

Hopefully, if anyone else comes across this problem, one/both of the above changes will fix it.

Comment: Hi, your fix worked for all test devices except for that old HTC phone with android 6.0.  I updated my question with the result.

Comment: Just want to make sure I'm interpreting correctly: this HTC phone also uses ES 3.0, not an earlier version?

Comment: Update: Just thought of something. Your new shaders use highp, but apparently that's not supported on all smartphones. Can you check if it is supported, or check if using mediump removes the problem? A good rundown of this issue can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856861/is-it-ok-to-use-highp-in-fragment-shaders-for-ios-android

Comment: The HTC phone is using OpenGL ES 3.0 with shading language version: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00.  When I switched to using mediump in the fragment shader, I got the clear color if I clear the depth value to 0.0 through 0.8.  If I clear it to 1.0 (like I would like to) I get all zeros (what I initialized the vector to).  When I tried it on other devices, I got the expected test result (rgb=32767, a=65535) with the depth clear value set to 1.0.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the supported integer range on that phone isn't large enough? For mediump ints, only up to +1023 is guaranteed.

Also, I read your original question more thoroughly today, and I noticed you said you're using UNSIGNED_INT because it's the only one with 32 bits per channel. Doesn't GL_FLOAT also have 32 bits per channel? Maybe all of this headache is for nothing?

Comment: 32 bits per channel for a float doesn't mean 32 bits of precision, because some of those bits go to the exponent and sign.

Comment: Hi I updated the problem under "Update 2".  mediump uints are up to 65535 in GLSL 3.00 and I can't use a float surface because the higher bits per channel float surfaces are not supported for color rendering.  Thanks for all the help :-)

Comment: Hi Cerulean. Though I have a couple of ideas about what it could be, I don't have any that stand out, and I don't want to clutter this comment section too much. Is it possible for you to include the exact clearing and reading code you use in both the 0.8f case and the 0.1f case? Or do you think a chat could be started to facilitate more back-and-forth communication?

Comment: Hi Cerulean. Sorry for the 2-month delay in response. I do not know what it could be. I can think of ways I might try to debug it if I had access to the phone + code, e.g. changing the depth component to something other than 32F, but I don't have an "answer" that I can provide in a nice single comment or edit to my answer. Sorry. :( Have you tried the Khronos forums? https://community.khronos.org/c/opengl-general/opengl-es/7